# AVAudioPlayer takes a long time to start

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code. The code takes a long time to transition to. I have a segue that transitions to the code but the segue takes a long time to work. Does anyone know why?

```
 viewDidLoad() {
            if let url = URL(string: book.mediaUrl!) {
            do {
                let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
                try session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
                let soundData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: soundData)
                audioPlayer?.delegate = self
                audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
                audioPlayer?.volume = 1.0
                audioPlayer?.enableRate = true
                
                guard let player = audioPlayer else { return }
```

I have a feeling that Dispatch.global.async might help me in this situation. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `book.mediaUrl` is a *remote* URL. Therefore what you are doing is completely illegal. You must *never* call `Data(contentsOf: url)` to fetch remote data. Either play the sound as a remote URL using AVPlayer, or else download the data *first* with URLSession and then play it.